# PHP - How do I add onto an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array. I need to use array_push, or similar, to add a value onto the end of an array and assign it.

Code: http://pastebin.com/tNg7gZ91

```
array_push($playerHolo, 'player' => 'UsernameHere'); //invalid syntax (the =>)
var_dump($playerHolo);
```

I'm trying to add the value "player" and assign the string "UsernameHere" to it.

**Other Information**

```
array_push($playerHolo['1'], array('player' => 'UsernameHere'));
```

Displays

```
http://pastebin.com/GTDe8Ex9
```

Suggestions?

Comment: var_dump(array_push($playerHolo, array( 'player' => 'UsernameHere' ) ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

```
array_push($playerHolo, array('player' => 'UsernameHere'));
```

or

```
$playerHolo['player'] = 'UsernameHere';
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter must be an array using valid array syntax if it is an associative array:

```
array_push($this->playerHolo, array('player' => 'UsernameHere'));
array_push($this->playerHolo, ['player' => 'UsernameHere']);
```

But why don't you just use a simple assignment?

```
$this->playerHolo['player'] = 'UsernameHere';
```

You'll notice I used `$this->playerHolo`. This is because you are also using the wrong syntax for accessing class member variables. This will save you from the next error you will encounter.

Comment: @bad_boy You are correct. I've updated my answer accordingly.